# Sub Query Using Lambda Expression or Comprehension Syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I am new to MVC and EF. I am following the Database First approach. I have in my database 2 tables named tblSubject and tblPrerequisite. I mapped them to my application using EF. here are the picture of both diagrams:
[image]

[image]
now I need to execute a query that looks like this:

```
select Sc from tblSubject where Sc not in (Select Prerequisite from tblPrerequisite where Sc = @subjectCode) and Sc != @subjectCode
```

this query is supposed to retrieve all subjects that have not been assigned as prerequisites to the subject that I am passing as a parameter. The second condition is supposed to filter out the subject itself -because it satisfies the first condition-. I need to know how to do it using Lambda Expression or Comprehension Syntax. Please help if you can

EDIT: here is the code to my mapped Subject class

```
 public partial class Subject
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Subject()
    {
        this.tblSubjectScores = new HashSet<SubjectScore>();
        this.Prerequisite = new HashSet<Subject>();
        this.IsPrerequisiteFor = new HashSet<Subject>();
        this.tblSubject_Program = new HashSet<Subject_Program>();
    }

    public string Sc { get; set; }
    public string Name_EN { get; set; }
    public string Name_AR { get; set; }
    public byte CCH { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubjectScore> tblSubjectScores { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Prerequisite { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> IsPrerequisiteFor { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Subject_Program> tblSubject_Program { get; set; }
}
```

this is the Action Method I am using for testing

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Subject s = db.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sc == "Acc102");
        var notYetAssigned = db.Subjects.Where(x => s.Prerequisite.Any(y=> y.Sc == s.Sc && y.Sc!=x.Sc) && x.Sc != s.Sc).ToList();
        return View(notYetAssigned);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I follow what you are asking but this is my attempt:

```
tblSubject.Where(s => tblPrerequisite.Any(p => p.Sc != sc) && s.Sc != sc).ToList()
```

See working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8CEHQl)

Comment: unfortunately, the two tables have been mapped as one but with 2 navigation properties. tblsubject1 refers to the collection of Prerequisites for a certain subject object, while, tblsubjects refers to the collection of subjects that a certain subject object is a prerequisite to.

Comment: You should show the code for your classes in your original post.

Comment: I did what you asked. Is there anything else you need?

Comment: I still think what I posted should work, what issues are you having with it?

Comment: I wrote something similar to what you proposed before I asked the question and it gave me this error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'GFIS.Models.Subject'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

and I checked the SQL Server Profiler and I saw that the query was returning only the subjects that are considered as prerequisites to the subject that I am choosing. It gave me that error when I tried to pass that list to a view that has a model class of Subject